# Accessing protected member in base class from a derived class

Tags: c++, class, protected, derived-class

I have the following snippet of code:

```
const int DATE_LENGTH = 6;

class BaseClass {
    protected:
        int date[DATE_LENGTH];
        int year;
    public:
        BaseClass(){}
        BaseClass(int *d) {
            for (int i = 0; i < DATE_LENGTH; i++) { date[i] = d[i];}
            year = 1900 + date[4] * 10 + date[5];
        }
        void printYear() {
            cout << year << endl;
        }
};

class DerivedClass : public BaseClass {
    public:
        DerivedClass() {}
        void printYear() {
            cout << year << endl;
        }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int dob[] = {1, 6, 1, 0, 9, 0};
    BaseClass base(dob);
    base.printYear(); // prints 1990

    DerivedClass derived;
    derived.printYear(); // prints 1439156608
}
```

I'm having trouble understanding why the output from `printYear()` in my derived class is outputting junk. Am I missing something very obvious?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Your default constructors don't initialize anything, so you get whatever happens to be in memory.

Comment: @T.C.: That's not quite true, the base subobject did get initialized. The language mandates that this happens. It's just that a very poor initialization was chosen.

Comment: @RetiredNinja: That's not actually something you can guarantee. It's undefined behaviour, and you might get something from memory, or a pizza, or lose your job.

Comment: You can get pizzas from undefined behaviour? Full speed ahead!

Comment: @KerrekSB You're right, I demand my pizza! :)

Comment: I suppose with my luck, it'll be a $50 pizza.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default constructor of class `BaseClass`

```
BaseClass(){}
```

does not initislize data members `date` and `year`

This default constructor is called by the default constructor of class `DerivedClass` when you create object derived

```
DerivedClass derived;
```

So these data members have arbitrary values and your program has undefined behaviour.

Change the derived class the following way

```
class DerivedClass : public BaseClass {
    public:
        using BaseClass::BaseClass;
        DerivedClass() {}
        void printYear() {
            cout << year << endl;
        }
};
```

and create object derived as

```
DerivedClass derived( dob );
```

Or instead of the using declaration you can yourself  explicitly define a constructor in class DerivedClass that has one parameter of type `int *` and calls the corresponding constructor of the base class. For example

```
class DerivedClass : public BaseClass {
    public:
        DerivedClass() {}
        DerivedClass( int *d ) : BaseClass( d ) {}
        void printYear() {
            cout << year << endl;
        }
};
```

Answer (score 4):

Your program has undefined behaviour. The default constructor of `DerivedClass`, which you are using, does not initialize the `year` member.

If you wanted to initialize the base member, you could do that by calling an appropriate base constructor, or by assigning the value directly.

```
DerivedClass() { year = 1999; }
```

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that's UB and cannot just be unspecified values?

Comment: @Deduplicator, Yes, `year` is uninitialized and an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is performed on it.

Answer (score 0):

The other provided answers only deal with part of the issue, partly because the *date* itself is ***never*** defined in the DerivedClass default constructor of either currently provided, and the other part being the BaseClass default constructor **still** has no defined value for either class variable (date or year). If the following code is used, depending what the default date and year should be, no additional change is actually required for the DerivedClass.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const int DATE_LENGTH = 6;

class BaseClass {
    protected:
        int date[DATE_LENGTH];
        int year;
    public:
        BaseClass()
        {
            int date[] = {1, 6, 1, 0, 9, 0};
            year = 1900 + date[4] * 10 + date[5];
        }
        BaseClass(int *d)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < DATE_LENGTH; i++) { date[i] = d[i];}
            year = 1900 + date[4] * 10 + date[5];
        }
        void printYear() {
            cout << year << endl;
        }
};

class DerivedClass : public BaseClass {
    public:
        DerivedClass() {}
        void printYear() {
            cout << year << endl;
        }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int dob[] = {1, 6, 1, 0, 9, 0};
    BaseClass base(dob);
    base.printYear(); // prints 1990

    DerivedClass derived;
    derived.printYear(); // prints 1439156608
    return 0;
}
```

Application Output

```
1990
1990
```